# Unable to save data correctly on Angular using Hibernate

Tags: java, angular, hibernate

I am working on a small app where people can like posts they like, but I can't manage to do it. The backend sent a "Not-null property references a transient value" error which I tried to solve by adding "cascade = CascadeType.All" in the entities causing the issue, but when the data is saved, it also saves new items in child tables.
To be more precise, I have this *Thumbsup* item to save, which has 3 columns (and all 3 are foreign keys) : *fk_account, fk_merch* and *fk_post*. When saving the *Thumbsup*, it creates a *Merch* item and then saves its id in fk_merch, which I do not want here.

Here is my **thumbsup.java** :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Thumbsup {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int thumbsupId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_post", referencedColumnName = "postId")
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_merch", nullable = true, referencedColumnName = "merchId")
    private Merch merch;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_account", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "accountId")
    private Account account;

    public static class Builder {
        int thumbsupId;
        Post post;
        Merch merch;
        Account account;

        public Builder setThumbsupId(int thumbsupId) {
            this.thumbsupId = thumbsupId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setPost(Post post) {
            this.post = post;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setMerch(Merch merch) {
            this.merch = merch;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAccount(Account account) {
            this.account = account;
            return this;
        }

        public Thumbsup build() {
            return new Thumbsup(thumbsupId, post, merch, account);
        }
    }
}
```

**merch.java** :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Merch {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int merchId;
    @NotNull
    private String itemname;
    @NotNull
    private double itemprice;
    private boolean active;
    private Date creation_date;
    private Date update_date;
    private Date deletion_date;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_artist", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "artistId")
    private Artist artist;

    public static class Builder {
        int merchId;
        String itemname;
        double itemprice;
        boolean active;
        Date creation_date = new Date();
        Date update_date;
        Date deletion_date;
        Artist artist;

        public Builder setMerchId(int merchId) {
            this.merchId = merchId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setItemname(String itemname) {
            this.itemname = itemname;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setItemprice(double itemprice) {
            this.itemprice = itemprice;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setCreation_date(Date creation_date) {
            this.creation_date = creation_date;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setUpdate_date(Date update_date) {
            this.update_date = update_date;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setDeletion_date(Date deletion_date) {
            this.deletion_date = deletion_date;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setArtist(Artist artist) {
            this.artist = artist;
            return this;
        }

        public Merch build() {
            return new Merch(merchId, itemname, itemprice ,active, creation_date, update_date, deletion_date, artist);
        }
    }
}
```

**post-structure.component.ts** :

```
export class PostStructureComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() post!: Post;
  credential!: Credential;
  accountDetail!: Account;
  artist!: Artist;
  selectedPost!: Post;
  thumbsup!: Thumbsup;
  thumbsups!: Thumbsup[];
  postForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(public artistService: ArtistService,
              public postService: PostService,
              public thumbsupService: ThumbsupService,
              public accountService: AccountService,
              public auth: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.me().subscribe((response: ApiResponse) => {
      this.credential = CredentialHelper.credentialFromDto(response.data as CredentialDto);
      this.accountService.getDetail(this.credential.account.accountId.toString()).subscribe((account: Account) => {
        this.accountDetail = account;
        this.artistService.getDetail(this.accountDetail.accountId.toString()).subscribe((artist: Artist) => {
          this.artist = artist;
          this.thumbsupService.getListByPost(this.post.postId.toString()).subscribe((thumbsups: Thumbsup[]) => {
            this.thumbsups = thumbsups;
            this.thumbsups.forEach(thumbsup => {
              if (thumbsup.account.accountId == this.accountDetail.accountId){
                this.thumbsup = thumbsup;
              }
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }

  onLike():void {
    let newThumbsup = {
       thumbsupId: 0,
       account: this.accountDetail,
       merch: MerchHelper.empty(),
       post: this.post
     }

    if (this.thumbsup == undefined ||this.thumbsup.thumbsupId == 0){
this.thumbsupService.create(ThumbsupHelper.returnCreatePayload(newThumbsup)).subscribe();
    } else {
      this.thumbsupService.deleteThumbsup(this.thumbsup.thumbsupId.toString()).subscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

**thumbsup.helper.ts** :

```
export class ThumbsupHelper {

  public static empty(): Thumbsup {
    return {
      thumbsupId: 0,
      account: AccountHelper.empty(),
      merch: MerchHelper.empty(),
      post: PostHelper.empty()
    }
  }
public static returnCreatePayload(thumbsup: Thumbsup): ThumbsupCreatePayload {
    return {
      account: thumbsup.account,
      merch: thumbsup.merch,
      post: thumbsup.post
    }
  }
```

I know that there are several and serious issues in my Angular code, such as getting *credential*, *accountDetail* and *artist* this way but I plan to modify this later, as well as . Also, I think that I should use Observables to manage data changes on thumbsup and evaluate if it exists or not to decide which method to call, but I have difficulties with it.

If anything is missing, I'll add it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to entities that already exist, you will have to load them via `EntityManager.find(Class entityClass, Object id)` or get a proxy reference to the object via `EntityManager.getReference(Class entityClass, Object id)`.

So instead of using `CascadeType.ALL` in `Thumbsup`, you will have to set the fields of the associations `merch`, `post` and `account` with the object returned by `find` or `getReference`.

Comment: In fact I'd want to save my `Thumbsup` while setting the value of `merch` to null if the value of `post` isn't, is there a way to do this ?

Comment: It's code, so yes, in your Java code you simply do something like `if (thumbsup.getPost() == null) { thumbsup.setMerch(null); }`